# Resequence table data after deletion of row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with 3 column of which *first column is a button and second column is id*. Now when user clicks on the button of specific row that row should be deleted. Up to this point everything wo$rks fine. But another requirement is **re-sequencing the table data.** I mean the column id should be re-sequence. For example:

First table data:

```
   | id | another-column
b1 | 1  | abc
b2 | 2  | xyz
b3 | 3  | def
b4 | 4  | qwe
```

Now when user deletes second row which have id=2 then table data should be as follows:

```
   | id | another-column
b1 | 1  | abc
b3 | 2  | def
b4 | 3  | qwe
```

Here `b1/b2/b3/b4` are buttons for deletion of particular row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly easy to set this sequential id value inside the getValueAt(row, col) of your Abstract Table Model.

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
   if (col == 1) 
      return int (row + 1);
      .....
}
```

Set the model again inside the action event of your buttons. The model will repaint the JTable correctly after a button has been pressed.